# Control Zipfile directory structure

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to save a zipfile in the /tmp directory. Here is the code I have:

```
import zipfile
log.info('ZippingXMLFile...')

myfilepath = '/tmp/%s' % self.file_name
myzippath = myfilepath.replace('.xml', '.zip')

zipfile.ZipFile(myzippath, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED).write(myfilepath)
```

This saves the zip file in the `/tmp` directory. However, when I double click the zip file to unzip it. It creates the `zip` file within a new `tmp` directory. How would I save the zipped file as `file.xml` instead of `/tmp/file.xml` in the `tmp` directory ?

Or, maybe there's an easier way to do this using the `subprocess` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change directory to `/tmp` before you create the zip file and then change back out when you've finished:

```
import zipfile
import os

log.info('ZippingXMLFile...')

saved = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('/tmp')
myzippath = self.file_name.replace('.xml', '.zip')
zipfile.ZipFile(myzippath, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED).write(self.file_name)
os.chdir(saved)
```